# smooth() method level parameter

Tags: image-processing, processing, smoothing, java

I have been checking some code for a project of mine and saw something interesting in PApplet and PGraphics classes related with smooth() methods

Below is the piece of code from PAppplet.java

```
public void smooth() {
  if (recorder != null) recorder.smooth();
  g.smooth();
}

public void smooth(int level) {
  if (recorder != null) recorder.smooth(level);
  g.smooth(level);
}
```

Here both g and recorder objects are instances of PGraphics.java class and in that class, here are the smooth methods:

```
public void smooth() {
  smooth = true;
}
/**
 *
 * @param level either 2, 4, or 8
 */
public void smooth(int level) {
  smooth = true;
}
```

Basically, setting different levels of smooth does not seem to be working. I have tried to put different numbers like 32 64 8 and so on but result didnt change at all. and as you can check the api page on http://processing.org/reference/smooth_.html it says smoothing levels should be working, but simply it is does not.

can anyone explain why the pieces of code above dont do anything with the levels although it is written in the API?

Answer (score 0):

You're not looking at the public API, that code is the internal code for compiling the Processing interpreter. So: welcome to the real world, where documentation and code don't always agree, especially when a project is ramping up for a new, full revision release. If you want answers about this from the developers you probably want to ask them directly by posting a question over on the new github code repo: https://github.com/processing/processing

(For future reference: the API is documented on http://processing.org/reference. If it's not mentioned there, even if it's in the source code, it's not part of the API. It's in there to make the interpreter do its job when it gets compiled by Java)